# In which Jewish book does it say that the body is like a house and the mouth is it's entry?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parts-of-the-body, symbols-symbology

Looking for a Jewish source for this concept.

Comment: The body/house image can be found here https://www.sefaria.org/Derekh_Chayim.1.5.9?lang=bi

Comment: Also refer to the Shlah who says "ונקרא גוף בית" - https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Aseret_HaDibrot%2C_Shevuot%2C_Torah_Ohr.4.22?vhe=Shenei_Luchot_HaBrit,_based_on_Amsterdam,_1698_ed._Part_II&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en